# Why is "as fit as a fiddle" about being fit and well?

Tags: etymology, idioms

[This article](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/40250.html) is on the origin of the idiom *as fit as a fiddle*. It is said that

> of course the 'fiddle' here is the colloquial name for violin. 'Fit'
>   didn't originally mean healthy and energetic, in the sense it is often
>   used nowadays to describe the inhabitants of gyms. When this phrase
>   was coined '**fit' was used to mean 'suitable, seemly'**, in the way we
>   now might say 'fit for purpose'.

Was a fiddle really so suitable? Anyway, even if a fiddle is or was always suitable, how is this fact connected with good health?

Comment: Research: https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/40250.html

Comment: The expression goes back to the early 1600s, according to Christine Ammer, _American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms_, who also says, "The original allusion of this simile has been lost. Its survival is probably due to to the pleasant sound of its alliteration." Still, it's a potentially interesting question—and one that seems not to have been asked at this site previously.

Comment: In making idioms the use of alliteration was always very important. Compare your example with 'as cool as a cucumber'.

Comment: The expression's awkwardness today is perhaps reflected by the number of modern variations that reflect irony e.g. "as fit as a flea", "as fit as a ferret" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Know Your Phrase](https://www.knowyourphrase.com/fit-as-a-fiddle) has this to say,

> This phrase's origin is not clear. However, it may have something to
>   do with the maintenance involved in keeping a musical instrument in
>   good condition. Indeed, instruments like guitars, flutes, drums and
>   others require a level of care to keep them in good shape and 
>   functioning properly.
>
> For example, let's take a look at fiddles. These typically refer to
>   stringed instruments, such as a violin (there is one portrayed in the
>   picture above). In order to help a violin remain in a working state,
>   its strings must be replaced if they break, tiny pegs need to be kept
>   tightened, and it should be cleaned every now and then to prevent dust
>   buildup. This sort of maintenance keeps the violin healthy or "fit,"
>   so to speak.
>
> So at some point, it seems a person's health started to be compared to
>   a well-maintained fiddle, though why this musical instrument was
>   chosen out of all the others, that I do not know.
>
> Anyhow, this saying goes back to at least the early 17th century. It's
>   written in a book entitled English-men for my Money, by Haughton
>   William in the year 1616. There's a part from it that reads:
>
> "This is excellent ynfayth, as fit as a fiddle."
>
> That means this expression is over 400 years old, and it could very
>   well be much older.

I agree with @user307254's comment about alliteration.